# each section of a pie chart to a random color in chartsjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using chartsJS to show a pie chart.
I each time the page refreshes the chart will have a different number of sections.
I am trying to set each section to a random color.

I ac create a random colour no problem by:

```
<script>
const randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (235 - 52 + 1) + 52);
const randomRGB = () => `rgb(${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()})`;
</script>
```

I can then set the pie chart sections to this color by using:

```
backgroundColor: randomRGB(),
```

The whole pie chart turns the random color.
How can I declare a loop that will set each section of the pie to a random color. note the number of pie sections will often change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a scriptable option for the backgroundColor for this:

```js
const randomNum = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (235 - 52 + 1) + 52);
const randomRGB = () => `rgb(${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()}, ${randomNum()})`;

const options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: () => (randomRGB())
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```